# Google Sheet conditional lookup by a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two sheets
SheetA with columns

```
Courier | From | To    | Weight (kg) | Price  
DHL     |  US  | China | 8           | (Derived from SheetB) 
DHL     |  US  | China | 15          | (Derived from SheetB)
```

SheetB with columns

```
Courier | From | To    | Min  | Max        |Price  
DHL     |  US  | China | 0.01 | 5          | 10  
DHL     |  US  | China | 5.01 | 10         | 20  
DHL     |  US  | China | 10.01| (infinity) | 50
```

How can I get SheetA to return "Price" with a lookup function?

**Result:**

```
Courier | From         | To         | Weight (kg) | Price
DHL     |  US          | China      | 8           | 20
DHL     |  US          | China      | 15          | 50
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: It defies belief that you have not or could not do any research on this. Start with the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) and then Google "google sheets vlookup".

Comment: I do know vlookup, but I only know the basic vlookup. Can't figure out the multiple matching cum condition matching like >=, <=. One thing I noticed the community quite fierce here... I research, crack my head for hours before post the question and yet people bad rated it :( what's da problem here

Comment: The community isn't fierce but it expects your work and research to be included with your question. It might have been different if you had put "Can't figure out the multiple matching cum condition matching like >=, <=." in your question. In fact, ">=, <=" don't apply. `VLOOKUP` has a setting `[is_sorted]` - the name is a bit misleading but it really means that if it = FALSE then it will only return _an exact match_ **BUT** if = TRUE then **the nearest match (less than or equal to the search key)** is returned. There's more in the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318#).

Comment: Your the freight rate is fixed for three weight ranges (Col D&E): 0-5, 6-10 and 10-infinity. But actually you only need Column D: 0+, 6+ and 10+. Shipment#1 weights 8, more than 0+ but less than 10+. So if you lookup the weight in Column D **AND if `[is_sorted]` = TRUE** then the nearest match (less than or equal to the search key) is 5 = Price20. Your formula is `=vlookup(D2,SheetB!$D$2:$F$4,3,true)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D, SheetB!D2:F, 3, 1), ))
```

[image]